# Retrieve the application context from a Thread in android

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

Is posible to retrieve the Applicaton Context from a non-main Thread with some kind of static call?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There are plenty (see below), but it is not recommended at all. You better pass the context when you create the thread through a customized constructor.

Example (again - **really discourged**):

in the activity:

```
class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    public static Context ctx;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // ...
        ctx = this;
        // ...
    }

    public static Context getLastSetContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

in the thread:

```
Context ctx = SomeActivity.getLastSetContext();
```

Comment: But using the ApplicationContext instead should not make memory leaks right? whats the problem with that?

Comment: This might be turned out fine in a simple case, but as your application will get bigger, you will see the downside of that by yourself, the dependency on some static field which is not guaranteed to have the instance, and might be changed (as you expand your application) is not safe IMHO, if you still wants to do it, I'm not the one to stop you.

Comment: That's certainly not only discouraged, but a recipe for large memory leaks. I would recommend to never never ever do that.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way by google to to create an instance of the application class.
From their documentation:

"There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton."

References
[1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
[2](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)